# UTF8 characters not showing correctly in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I am running out of ideas - Wordpress is refusing to save UTF-8 encoded characters correctly:
http://www.letosanezkou.com/

you can see that when I edit the post content directly in the MySQl DB it works correctly. I have verified the mysql db:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.24, for Linux (i686) using readline 5.1
Connection id:          2120
Current database:       leto_wp1
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.5.24-cll MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
```

and my wp-config has the default UTF-8 lines:

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

When I try to update the post, that was edited in phpmyadmin it will save the post incorrectly.

Any ideas on how to fix this please?

Comment: Presumably, either WP is not generating proper HTTP content-type headers so valid UTF-8 is then declared to be, say, Latin 1 and mojibake'd accordingly by browsers. Alternatively, the problem is that the WP editor runs in a browser which stubbornly sends all content pre- mojibake'd. -- That is your WP site never receives any UTF-8 as you'd expect it would, because your browser has kindly garbled it for you first.

Comment: Mybe you edited the file that shows the post and saved it in other formath than UTF-8.

Comment: Got any non-standard php.ini settings? Having `mbstring.encoding_translation` or something similar seems like a possible cause of this issue.

Comment: @TomEus also check for the PHP character set at your server end.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your help - the mbstring.encoding_translation was the culprit here, I turned it off and it works correctly